# Move an element of a list to another list

Tags: c#

The code below fails, and I guess it's cause the Remove()-method is ruining the loop order. But how do I fix it?

```
List<string> test = new List<string>();
List<string> test2 = new List<string>();
test.Add("test");
test.Add("test");
test.Add("test");
test.Add("test");
foreach(string t in test)
{
    test2.Add(t);
    test.Remove(t);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right about the problem, the solution is to iterate over a copy instead of the actual list

```
foreach(string t in test.ToList())
{
     test2.Add(t);
     test.Remove(t);
}
```

BTW, you can do what you want without using any loop:

```
test2.AddRange(test);
test.Clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

It fails because `foreach` iteration variables or read-only.

One way to work around the error is to change the `foreach` loop to a `for` loop, starting the loop from the last element so as to not mess up the order if you remove an element.